# Set the same elevation for all cards in recyclerview kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, material-components-android

I'm using this card xml in my item for recyclerview and it looks like the shadow increases when the position comes more down, but I want to make it one for all of them

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        style="?attr/materialCardViewElevatedStyle"
        android:id="@+id/crd"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:strokeWidth="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWsZ0.jpg)

I searched for a solution but I didn't find